# Uniqueness set for holomorphic function in $\mathbb{C}^n$

Tags: complex-analysis

We know that if $f:\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ is a holomorphic function and $f$ vanishes on a set $E\subset \mathbb{R} \subset \mathbb{C}$ such that $E$ has a limit point in $\mathbb{R}$ then $f$ is identically zero.

My question: Is the same is true in multivariable case? I.e. if $f:\mathbb{C}^n\to \mathbb{C}^n$ is a holomorphic function and $f$ vanishes on a set $E\subset \mathbb{R}^n \subset \mathbb{C}^n $ such that $E$ has a limit point in $\mathbb{R}^n$ then is $f$  identically zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(z_1,z_2,...,z_n)=(z_1,z_1,...,z_1)$ is a counterexample.

Comment: Sir thanking you for quick reply. Your counterexample pushed me to think whether the result holds for positive measure set in multivariable case. I asked that question in a different tab. Please give your thoughts.